# Updating scrollLeft / scrollTop not working while scrolling on Safari IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, mobile-safari, scroll-position

In my React application, the user is presented with a horizontally scrollable list and can scroll left / right to load more data.

When the user scrolls all the way to the left, I load more data and append it to the beginning of my list. This works fine, except that the scroll position seems to be reset to 0.

To solve this, I restore the scroll position after prepending the new data to my list. This works well on Android, but on IOS this doesn't work.

On IOS, the scrollLeft position of my DIV is still reset to 0 after rendering, even if I restore the scroll position after rendering. The strange thing seems to be that this only happens if the user was still scrolling when the rendering took place.

So it seems like on IOS Safari, setting the scrollLeft / scrollTop position of a div only works if the user is not currently scrolling that div.

Has anyone seen this before, and perhaps know a workaround?

Comment: Seems like I just found the same issue myself.